# Subscribe all users to Simplenews Newsletter

Tags: 8

We just installed Simplenews module. Is there a way to subscribe all our current users to one of the newsletters we created. This will be used to send important website updates. Therefore we don't want to skip users that have been registred to date.

We have a few thousands users, so a manual process will not work. Can this be done in the mysql database?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738403/drupal-simplenews-how-to-subscribe-all-existing-users

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

1. Go to Mysql and output the user_field-data table as a csv. Delete all
   the columns except the user emails.
2. Copy all the user emails to the clipboard.
3. Go to Admin  People  Simplenews

   You will see options to Mass Subscribe.
4. Paste the emails on the form. Select the newsletter and wait for a
   while.

If you have a long email list break it down in 500 or 1000 records at a time or the server may time out.